# NTP time off by 24 minutes

Tags: raspbian, ntp

I have added `dpkg-reconfigure ntp` to `bash.rc` and run it several times in the terminal.

I have changed my `timezone` around. I have gone to just ethernet and rebooted, and every single time, my pi time is off by 24 minutes.

I can't install anything, I can't even run `apt-get update`.

I am at a loss for ideas. Can anyone out there help me?

Comment: *"I can't even run apt-get update"* -- having your clock wrong won't cause this problem.

Comment: Not sure about apt-get, but I have seen cases of encryption protocols which failed to work if the time/date was incorrect.  Possibly protection against replay attacks.

Comment: I think the only constraint for apt might be if you appear to be doing certain kinds of things "before" something that's already happened, in which case it is just a 24 minute window.  I've had clocks off by some noticeable fraction of an hour -- or a day -- and never noticed `apt-get` not working (making it generally time sensitive would be a poor choice, I think, since it may be used places which make that a hassle).  The problem could be with connectivity period, in which case niether `ntp` nor `apt` would work.

Comment: very bizarre. I wiped noobs, and went straight to a raspbian image. not exactly a fix, as I can't tell if it was a config error, but everything works splendidly now.

Comment: Have you tried to set time by the National Bureau of Standards?  Here is how you set that up.  It is easy:  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/68811/how-do-i-set-raspbian-to-use-the-primary-time-server-time-nist-gov/68812